# Displaying error messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I seem to have trouble handling error messages. Here's my method:

```
  def destroy
     @user = User.find(current_user)
     @authorization = Authorization.find(params[:id])
     if @user.authorizations.count > 1
       @authorization.destroy
       redirect_to(user_path(current_user))
     else

...


     end
   end
```

I don't want a user to delete their last authorization (say, Facebook) because then the user won't have any authorizations associated with it and the account is lost. I want to send an error message that says why the destroy method fails, but I'm just not sure how. Everything I've tried just doesn't work.

I've tried things like @user.errors.add => "error message"

But it just shows up blank. I think my problem is with using render. If I try, for example:

```
 respond_to do |format|
         @user.errors[:base] << "Sorry, you can't delete your only authorized service."
         format.html render :template => "users/show"
      end
```

I get a problem because rails starts looking for the partials in users/show inside the authorizations directory for some reason, presumably because I'm calling the authorizations controller from a users view.

Here's how I display the flash in my views:

```
 def show_flash
      [:notice, :errors, :alert].collect do |key|
          msg = (flash[key].to_s + " (close)")
          content_tag(:div, (content_tag(:a, msg, :class => "#{key}", :href => "#", :onclick => "$('messages').slideUp(); return false;")), :id => key, :class => "flash_#{key}") unless flash[key].blank?
          end.join
    end
```

I can get notices to appear just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this seems to be working:

```
 respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to(@user, :alert => "Sorry, you can't delete your only authorized service.")}      
 end
```

But, this does not:

```
 respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to(@user, :errors => "Sorry, you can't delete your only authorized service.")}      
 end
```